# Creating a random number in a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a variable that is a string that includes a random number, but it keeps telling me that my syntax is invalid, highlighting the r in rand.

```
import random as rand
Smoke = str(rand.randint(20, 40)" Smoke Shells")
```

What mistake have I made here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in the code, like you shouldn't convert a string to a string

```py
str(" Smoke Shells")
```

and you can't add a string to an int.
This should work, though:

```py
import random as rand
Smoke = str(rand.randint(20, 40)) + " Smoke Shells"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting that syntax error because python is not sure what to do with the provided values.

What I would do is `smoke = str(rand.randint(20, 40)) + " Smoke Shells"`